# Process data with php in cycle

Tags: php, cycle

There is a file with a specified number of rows and php-script that processes the data. The problem is that I should define manually string in this script to process like this:
$ url = 'http://text.ru'; instead http://text.ru
How we can add to it looping all the rows from the file automatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the file handling API available in php to read from a file. Just read one line at a time from the file and process it. Look at the following link.

[PHP File Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp)

Comment: Could you show an example please? My knowledge of php is very low.

Comment: there is a step by step explanation present on the link I have provided along with the examples. Just see the link.